# how to use hover tag for a class?

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, animate.css

I am building a website using bootstrap and animate.css I want to add animation when the user hovers over a link the link should swing and for this, I used animate.css classes but now I don't know to hover tag in it please help

this is my navbar link code

```
 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active animate__animated animate__swing" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;">Home</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active animate__animated animate__swing" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;">Products</a></li>
 <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active animate__animated animate__swing" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;">contact us</a></li>
```

if I run this code then all three links will do swing animation when I will open the page but I want swing animation when I hover over a link

the animation is taken from [www.animate.css](https://animate.style/)

**UPDATE**

I have implemented the which i wanted to but now i am writting 2
javascript function for every one link and that is very unprofessional so please suggest me some good logic to implement the same thing

**MyLogic**

Script

```
function mouseover()
  {
    const el = document.getElementById("1");
    el.className = "nav-link active animate__animated animate__swing";
  }
  function mouseout()
  {
    const el = document.getElementById("1");
    el.className = "nav-link active";
  }
```

**HTML Code**

```
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="1" onmouseover="mouseover();" onmouseout="mouseout();" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="2" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;">Products</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" id="3"  href="\" style="font-size: 12px;">contact us</a></li>
```

Comment: Please provide a worling example to demonstrate the issue

Comment: https://animista.net/play/attention/wobble/wobble-hor-top this is what i am trying to acheive

Comment: [animate.css-dynamic](https://animate-dynamic.ga/) try this

Comment: @MohammedKhurram thanku for this i think it will do the work

Comment: @MohammedKhurram write this as an answer so that i can close this que

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript or jQuery for this.

**For example:-**

```
$(elem).mouseover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("animate__animated animate__flip");
  //You can add some other classes as well
}); 
//If you want the animation to happen every time you hover on element
$(elem).mouseout(function(){
  $(this).removeClass("animate__animated animate__flip");
});
```

**1 or more animations**

```
$(elem).mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("animate__animated animate__flip");
    //You can add some other classes as well
    this.addEventListener('animationend',() => {
       $(this).removeClass("animate__animated animate__flip");
       //the second animation now
       $(this).addClass("animate__animated animate__bounce");
    });
});
```

**Extras**

There is a library [animate.css-dynamic](https://github.com/KodingKhurram/animate.css-dynamic) which is simple to use with some utility classes and more.

For for your case using this library you can do something like this.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/KodingKhurram/animate.css-dynamic@main/animate.min.js"></script>

<h2 align="center"> Mouse over the links to animate</h2>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active ani_swing aniUtil_onMouse aniUtil_active" id="1" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;display: inline-block">Home</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active ani_bounce aniUtil_onMouse aniUtil_active" id="2" href="\" style="font-size: 12px;display: inline-block">Products</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active aniCus_OutIn-fadeOutLeft-fadeInRight aniUtil_onMouse aniUtil_active" id="3"  href="\" style="font-size: 12px;display: inline-block">contact us (this animation is special)</a></li>
```

visit [here](https://animate-dynamic.ga) for detailed documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery. use hover() to toggle the animation class.

### JQuery

```js
$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("animate__swing");
 });
```

or you can make it plain javascript using `mouseover` and `mouseout` events to toggle this animated classes.

### Javascript

```js
const atag = document.querySelectorAll("a");

 for (let i = 0; i < atag.length; i++) {
     atag[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
       cbox[i].classList.add("animate__swing");
     });
     atag[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
       cbox[i].classList.remove("animate__swing");
     });
 }
```

Comment: i am not using jquery and i am not into javascript so can u please help me with code

Comment: There is no way. you should use script in this time.

Comment: I mean i don't know how to play with frontend using javascript other wise i know javascript

Comment: I just edit my answer to add javascript code.

Comment: can you please explain how this is working

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a");` selects all `a` tag elements. and I accessed all elements through `for loop` and added the events to this element.  the mouse is `on` the `a` tag the `animate__swing` class added into the 'a' tag. the mouse is `out` the `a` tag the `animate__swing` class remove from the 'a' tag. for more refer this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243926/discussion-between-vaitheeswaran-and-naveen-singla).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JS than you should use `mouseover` and `mouseout` for toggle action.

```
$("a").on("mouseover",function()
{                  
   $("a").classList.add("animate__swing");
});

$("a").on("mouseout",function()
{                  
   $("a").classList.remove("animate__swing");
});
```

Comment: Where do you see that they are using jQuery?

Comment: Who said JQuery @cloned? My code is in JS.

Comment: hey bro i used javascript and it worked i used id and onmouseover method but the thing if i am using that means i have to write 2 function for one link and that is very unprofessional so please suggest me some good method to implement the same logic


  `function mouseover()
  {
    const el = document.getElementById("1");
    el.className = "nav-link active animate__animated animate__swing";
  }
  function mouseout()
  {
    const el = document.getElementById("1");
    el.className = "nav-link active";
  }`

Comment: `$('a').on` is jQuery syntax, not normal JS.

Comment: your code is jquery :P